# Bring a string from controller in a textbox (asp mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserDetails user)
        {
            user.UserEmail = "Email";
            return View();
        }
```

And this lines

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserEmail)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
```

How can I past a value from the controller in the view (in the input box for the UserEmail)?

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass values from the controller to the view.. I would use viewData and viewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserDetails user)
    {
        user.UserEmail = "Email";
        ViewData["ArbitraryName"] = user;
        return View();
    }
```

In your view:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserEmail)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
@{ var user = ViewBag.ArbitraryName;}
```

To access specific data from there, use `@user.YourData`

See here for more on this specific topic:
https://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: The person who asked the question is trying to bind model attributes to a text box. Doing it with ViewData or ViewBag is not recommended as it leads to badly maintainable code. They would be better off using proper models.

Comment: "trying to bind model attributes to a text box" this was never explicitly stated.. and Shyju's answer already included proper models. Merely offering more options for OP, kid

Answer (score 2):

Pass your `UserDetails` object to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index(UserDetails user)
{
   user.UserEmail = "Email";
   return View(user);
}
```

Assuming your razor view (`Index.cshtml`) is strongly typed to `UserDetails`

```
@model UserDetails 
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserEmail)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
```

Comment: Sorry i poste it as an answer